# Partially filled array and NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, null

I'm having some issues, I think I know what's going I just don't know how to fix it.

The assignment is the user can enter *up to* 500 int's (using BufferedReader not scanner) and pass the int's into methods and do some calculations.  Input comes in on one line with a space in between and stops when user hits enter.  **My problem is with calculating the median, right now I'm getting a NullPointerException.**  I did have my int array initialized to a size of 500 and the string array not initialized but the Median method was always calculating to 0 and I realized it was because I was passing all 500 indexes into the calculation and the indexes that weren't being used were set to zero.

**I don't know how to initialize the arrays to 500 and not get errors or calculate incorrectly if the user does not enter all 500 int's.**

Note: no prompts to the user and no exit phrases allowed, it should exit when user hits enter.  Here is my code, thank you for any tips or pointing me in the right direction!

```
public class StatPackage {
    private static int intScoresArr[];
    private static String inputArr[] = new String [500];

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String inputValues;
    double count = 0;
    double average, median;
    NumberFormat NF = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    NF.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    NF.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    InputStreamReader ISR = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(ISR);

    while((inputValues = BR.readLine()) != null) {
        inputArr = inputValues.split("\\s");
        for(int i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
            intScoresArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputArr[i]);
            count++;
        }
        //Call calcMean calculate average
        average = calcMean(intScoresArr, count);
        System.out.println(NF.format(average));

        //Call calcMedian, calculate median
        median = calcMedian(intScoresArr, count);
        System.out.println(median); 
    }
}

//Calculate the mean (average)
public static double calcMean(int scores[], double count) {
    double average = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
        average = average + scores[i] / count;
    }
    return average;
}


public static double calcMedian(int scores[], double count) {
    Arrays.sort(scores);
    double middle = 0;
    int countInt;

    if(count % 2 == 1) {
        count = (count + 1) / 2;        
        middle = scores[(int)count - 1];
    }
    else if(count % 2 == 0) {
        count = (count + 1) / 2;
        middle = (scores[(int)count] + scores[(int)count+1]) / 2;
    }
    return middle;
}
```

Comment: Put in a null check? `if(scores[i] != null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
private static int intScoresArr[];
```

only *declares* the array, it doesn't create it. The code you've posted doesn't create the array anywhere, so `intScoresArr` is `null`.

Somewhere, you need

```
intScoresArr = new int[x];
```

...where `x` is the size of the desired array.

I say "somewhere" because the code uses `intScoresArr` in a `while` loop that doesn't seem to need `intScoresArr` to be a field, much less a static field. It seems like it should be a local:

```
while((inputValues = BR.readLine()) != null) {
    inputArr = inputValues.split("\\s");
    int[] intScoresArr = new int[inputArr.length]; // <============= here
    for(int i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
        intScoresArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputArr[i]);
        count++;
    }
    //Call calcMean calculate average
    average = calcMean(intScoresArr, count);
    System.out.println(NF.format(average));

    //Call calcMedian, calculate median
    median = calcMedian(intScoresArr, count);
    System.out.println(median); 
}
```

(And remove the static declaration.)

Similarly, `intScores` shouldn't be a class-wide static either; if you make it local, bugs like this one in `calcMean` get caught by the compiler:

```
public static double calcMean(int scores[], double count) {
    double average = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
    //                 ^------------------------------ should be `scores`
        average = average + scores[i] / count;
    }
    return average;
}
```

Amusingly, you've created an array you never use and stored it in `intScores`:

```
private static String inputArr[] = new String [500];
// This array is never used -------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You immediately overwrite the value of `inputArr` in your `while` loop:

```
inputArr = inputValues.split("\\s");
```

#### Summary

1. Remove the class-wide declarations of `intScoresArr` and `inputArr`
2. Declare them in `main`, either at the top of `main` or within the `while` loop:

   ```
   while((inputValues = BR.readLine()) != null) {
       int[] inputArr = inputValues.split("\\s");
       int[] intScoresArr = new int[inputArr.length];
   ```
3. Fix `calcMean` to use its input argument.
4. Look for other similar errors.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing in the for loop where I parse the inputArr?

Comment: @sjud9227: No. You're trying to fill in its entries, but you haven't created the array itself.

Comment: Ok so if I initialize it to a size of 500 I get problems when the user doesn't enter all 500 elements because the left overs are set to 0's

Comment: @sjud9227: I never said you should initialize it to 500.

Comment: I would suggest using `ArrayList` in your code instead of Array.  Arrays are immutable which is obviously giving you problems.  `ArrayList` will work much better given your objective.

Comment: It's for an assignment, haven't got to collections yet.  @T.J. if I do intScoresArr = new int[x] and set x = 500; isn't that the same thing?

Comment: Ah wow, good call on setting it to the length of inputArr.  Thank you for the well thought out explanation that was incredible helpful!!   As far as all the mistakes you've pointed out, I've been messing with this for hours and changing all kinds of stuff...I originally had it as score.length and I honestly don't why I put the arrays as static data fields.  Oh I see what you're saying with inputArr, but I need an array initialized to 500...

Comment: @T.J Crowder What you said helped but I need to initialize the array to 500 and that's where all my problems come in

Comment: @sjud9227: *"but I need to initialize the array to 500"* There's no reason *in that code* for you to do that. You shouldn't use magic numbers in code. You only need `intScoresArr` to be as long as `inputArr`, no longer, no shorter.

Comment: The reason is per the assignment instructions

Comment: @sjud9227: :-) That's why I said there's no reason "in that code." Double-check that you're reading the assignment correctly, because it's a silly requirement, which most likely means there's a misunderstanding somewhere. You *can* make it 500 elements long, but then you need another variable to remember how many of those are "real," which is just dumb.

Comment: I think it just needs to be a max of 500 elements...I figured that means you have to initialize the array to 500?  I'm very new to this so if I'm the one being dumb and not the assignment please be nice  lol.

Comment: @sjud9227: I don't think it's you. I mean, if the numbers really come all on one line, space-delimited, then how are you supposed to limit them to 500? Are you supposed to do `int[] inputArr = inputValues.split("\\s");` then `if (inputArr.length > 500) { System.out.println("Can't do that many"); }` or some such? I'd put a comment above the `split` line saying "Didn't see any reason to limit this to 500 but if we did, it would be with `if (inputArr.length > 500)`" and move on, using the exact sizes needed.

Comment: Good point.   I have class in the morning I'll ask the professor.  Can buffered reader read directly into a String array or only a String?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming it's all on one line because that's how all our other assignments have been but maybe it's seperate lines and then a blank line will end the input...

Comment: @sjud9227: Well, if you were doing individual lines, you *would* need to precreate `intScoresArr` and then limit the loop using `intScoresArr.length`. You'd need a separate variable to remember the number of *actual* entries you'd received (say, `count`) so you could ignore the extra ones in `calcMean` and such.

Comment: How would I use count to ignore the extra ones in Median though?  That's where the problem came in because there were too many zeros to get an accurate median.  Makes sense in Mean because I'd use count as the number of times to loop right?

Comment: @sjud9227: I'd say you'd probably be best off creating a new array as soon as you're done with your input loop, one that's only as long as it needs to be. (See `Arrays.copyOf`) Then you don't have to pass around extra variables, and you can use things like `Arrays.sort`.